# Json get values in android

Tags: android, json

This is my json output:

```
{"Please enter valid mobile no!!":1}
```

This is my code:

```
jArray = new JSONArray(results);
JSONObject json_data=null;
json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(0);
int result=json_data.getInt("1"); // get the json string name
System.out.println("message "+result);
```

but it's giving me an exception.

this is my php code:-

```
$arr = array("Please enter valid mobile no!!"=>1); 
echo json_encode($arr); exit
```

How can I retrieve the value?

Comment: It is an object, not a array.

Comment: what the result of `echo json_encode($arr);` is?

Comment: {"Please enter valid mobile no!!":1}

Comment: @RahulRawat :  if this is extact json string `{"Please enter valid mobile no!!":1}` then get value as :`JSONObject json = new JSONObject(results); String str_value=json.getString("Please enter valid mobile no!!");` becuase current json string contain only one object

Comment: ρяσѕρєя K but my output:- -{"1":"Please enter valid mobile no!!"}

Answer (score 0):

The key in your example is "Please enter valid mobile no!!"
So `int result=json_data.getInt("Please enter valid mobile no!!");` should return 1, not the other way around.

If you want to use 1 as a key you should use:

```
    String result=json_data.getString("1");  //get the String with key 1
```

php code:

```
    $arr = array(1 => "Please enter valid mobile no!!");  //key => value
```

Comment: I've edited my answer, if you still get an error you should change the 1 in your php code to "1".

Comment: checked but got exception. ouput:-{"1":"Please enter valid mobile no!!"}

Comment: Could you be more specific?